# How to make Joomla 2.5 form responsive in Yootheme site?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, joomla

Form:http://www.pawsingoodcare.com/contact-us
Joomla 2.5.19, Yootheme Nano.

Form is set up and working the way client wants - with one exception: form breaks when see on smart phone sized viewport.

I've been able to edit other parts of the form using custom.css built into the theme. Example:

```
h3 { font-size: 18px; line-height: 18px; display:none;}
```

I can even manipulate the form width by using

```
#system .item > *:last-child {
margin-bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
   }
```

However, I've tried using media-queries Example:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
width:50%;
min-width:200px;
   }
```

Q: how to make the form responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kheema said, we getting an access denied error which means there is probably some script running that only allows your IP address to view the site.

As for your media query, the reason why your isn't working is because you haven't defined which element to apply the style to. Have a look at this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 321px)     /* define the min width */
and (max-device-width : 768px) {   /* define the max width */

    input, textarea {              /* define the element */
        width: 100%;
    }
    /* continue adding more code */

}
```

Comment: puzzled by not accessing site.  Here's main site: <http://www.pawsingoodcare.com/> Can you access this?  If so there's link to contact form. This site access issue more urgent than the css - but will try your suggestion.

Comment: No, I can't access this either

Comment: Thanks @Lodder. 1. Where would I look for script or whatever that's causing access issue. 2. using suggested code - no change in form.  Do I need something in header? Site as whole not responsive. Or would adding code  to the media querie you suggested do that?

Comment: 1. I have no idea what's causing the access denied error. 
2. My code is simply to get you started off. As I can't see the form, I can't give you a more accurate answer

Comment: I was mistaken site is responsive, just not the Joomla form. I was checking via re-sizing browser. Site is not responsive when re-sized in FireFox.

Comment: Tech at Rochen (host) says it looks okay. Friend in next village also tried both link in this thread and a link I sent her. both worked okay. Please try again and if still blocked for you would you pm me via link in my profile results of going to this link? directrouter.com/ip.php Suggestion by tech.

Comment: I had geographic blocking on. Should be okay now.

Comment: Pardon double posting; would let me use @ your name. Also could not get mini-Markdown to work. I discovered there is a template for phones: JTouch Mobile. It, too, has a customize folder which I renamed as asked and placed code there. Still no effect on the form.     @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) { /* Styles / input, textarea { / define the element / width: 100%; } / continue adding more code */ }

Comment: I told you that this code is to get you started iff. Of course if you just copy and psate it, not all of the form will be responsive. There are most likely other aspects of your site that are not responsive. Are you using Nano or Nano2/3 cause the first one if I rightly remember wasnt responsive. Could be mistaken though. Makw sure ypu also use your browser console to assist you as it comes in handy

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Nano is the July 2012 release and is responsive. It has a mobile section.  I tried the JTouch template& plugin that is installed but it indeed does not seem to be used. I have left it disabled and so am working in the custom.css within the Yootheme template. I have yet to succeed in getting firebug lite to work in iPhone. My computer is Windows. I do have Chrome Canary running Web Dev console emulating iPhone5. Will start exploring that shortly.

Comment: Done: In Chrome Canary, in Web Devolper with Emulation =Apple iPhone 5 on this page: <http://pawsingoodcare.com/contact-us>. Using these settings the Joomla contact form is responsive:    #system form.submission fieldset > div > input[type='text'], #system form.submission fieldset > div > input[type='password'] {
padding: 5px;
width: 92%;
}

#system form.submission fieldset > div > textarea { width: 95%;
; }

Comment: Thank you Lodder and Kheema for  yourprodding, supporting and for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting access denied alert so not sure what meta tags you used in your page..

Have you tired to using this way.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
 and (min-device-width : 320px)
 and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: thanks@Kheema I'm new to some of this...not sure what you were trying to access to receive access denied nor what you mean by meta tags in this context... tried using your setting with the #system .item code above with width at 50% = brought form to 50% desktop. Form still broke in small viewport    @media only screen {
 and (min-device-width : 320px)
 and (max-device-width : 480px) 
}
#system .item > *:last-child {
      width: 80%;
}

Comment: I was trying to access the link you posted here. but its gives me 404 error. and regarding the meta tags I was assuming that you are talking about iphone devices. IF you are concern about ihpone devices you must add these meta tags in your page under `<head>` tag. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"> `

Comment: Thank you @Kheema. I am pursuing the access denied issue.  I'm not sure where I would find the <head> tag area on a Joomla 2.5 site. Which file?

Comment: In server at root level search for template folder where you will see `NANO` theme folder and there search for index.php file where you can add any meta tag inside tag.

Comment: hmm. It's php: 
    // no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// include config  
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php');

// get warp
$warp = Warp::getInstance();

// load main template file, located in /layouts/template.php
echo $warp['template']->render('template');    Do I look in template.php?

Comment: Scott as per question if my answer is helpful for you then you may accept this answer.

Comment: It was indeed helpful about where to put the iPhone coding in header - though I haven't found the actual spot - see my last post....but my primary question is not yet answered.  I'm just learning StackExchange...will my checking 'answered' essentially close discussion or will it be like a Fb 'like'?

Comment: if your problem is not solved then you no need to accept the answer. its not something like hitting the like button in facebook. you should hit the checkmark if your problem solved. so in near future if any other user face same issue he can get benefited with the real working answer.

Comment: See my recent comment below - site is responsive in iPhone - just not the form.

Comment: Tech at Rochen (host) says it looks okay. Friend in next village also tried both link in this thread and a link I sent her. both worked okay. Please try again and if still blocked for you would you pm me via link in my profile results of going to this link? http://directrouter.com/ip.php Suggestion by tech.

Comment: I had geographic blocking on. Should be okay now.

Comment: I discovered there is a template for phones: JTouch Mobile. It, too, has a customize folder which I renamed as asked and placed code there. Still no effect on the form.    @media only screen
 and (min-device-width : 320px)
 and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
input, textarea {              /* define the element */
        width: 100%;
    }
    /* continue adding more code */
}

Comment: please check if JTouch component provide the responsive form or not.. otherwise you have to find the respective CSS and there you can add a responsive Css code. I never worked on JTouch component so I am not sure where you can find related css. by the way if you use `Firebug` Extension with the help of this Firebug extension you can find what css file are exactly applied.

Comment: I didn't know I could use Firebug in iPhone...googled and see I can...will do that in am...great thanks!

Comment: Found jTouch Mobile plugin entry - it was disabled. Enabeled it => big jTouch Mobile logo where menu would be - though form is responsive.  Could not get firebug lite working tonight per Martin Kool's tut. calling it a night...

Comment: great enjoy. I am happy I can help you in some way.

Comment: Thanks. See up date added above.

Comment: Congrats i saw the form in mobile and it fits as per device resution.

Comment: Thanks. A helpful discovery today was Developer Tools in Chrome Canary where I emulate the various mobile devices while exploring css.

Comment: thanks for sharing.. Chrome developer tool is growing day by day..thinking to left the `Firebug` developer toolbar.

Comment: I use Chrome for day to day browsing now instead of FireFox. I understand their development is faster - they keep up with needs and coding changes better. Now I use Chrome Canary for testing bec. of emulator.